# XGBRegressor sklearn wrapper and booster type

Tags: scikit-learn, xgboost

I am using XGBRegressor of scklearn wrapper to create xgboost model .

If the booster parameter upon some change between 'gblinear' and 'gbtree' ?

If not , what booster is used ?

Unfortunately I don't see some clear answer regrading the issue

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The sklearn wrapper does not allow you to change the booster parameter. It uses gbtree. I have filed an issue on this.

Comment: Have you had any answer on this issue you filed? I am currently encountering the same problem.